# List of assignment expressions

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I've bending my mind for a while, but I think I'm missing something, so may be someone will help.

Let's say I have following mapper class:

```
public class Mapping<TSource, TResult>
{
    private readonly Action<TSource, TResult> setter;

    public Mapping(Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression)
    {
        var newValue = Expression.Parameter(expression.Body.Type);
        var body = Expression.Assign(expression.Body, newValue);
        var assign = Expression.Lambda<Action<TSource, TResult>>(body, expression.Parameters[0], newValue);

        setter = assign.Compile();
    }

    public void Assign(TSource instance, TResult value)
    {
        setter(instance, value);
    }
}
```

And it is working fine:

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldMapProperty()
    {
        var testClass = new TestClass();

        var nameMapping = new Mapping<TestClass, string>(x => x.Name);
        var ageMapping = new Mapping<TestClass, int>(x => x.Age);

        nameMapping.Assign(testClass, "name");
        ageMapping.Assign(testClass, 10);

        Assert.AreEqual("name", testClass.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual(10, testClass.Age);       
    }
```

Thing is, that I would like to keep mappings for single object type into some collection  and TResult is getting in the way, as long as different properties have different types.
How to get rid of TResult nicely?

**Update:**
looks like I wasn't clear enough, so this would be sample how would I use it:

```
 public class Mapping<TSource, TResult>
{
    private readonly Action<TSource, TResult> setter;
    private readonly string columnName;

    public Mapping(Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression, string columnName)
    {
        this.columnName = columnName;            

        var newValue = Expression.Parameter(expression.Body.Type);
        var body = Expression.Assign(expression.Body, newValue);
        var assign = Expression.Lambda<Action<TSource, TResult>>(body, expression.Parameters[0], newValue);

        setter = assign.Compile();
    }

    public void Assign(TSource instance, DataRow row)
    {
        setter(instance, row[columnName]);
    }
}
```

And then I would have some MappingConfiguration class, that would let me do this:

```
MappingConfiguration.For<TestClass>()
  .Map(x => x.Name, "FirstName")
  .Map(x => x.Age, "Age");
```

And finaly some MappingEngine class, that would take DataTable and MappingConfiguration as input and produce `IEnumerable<TestClass>` as output.

**Update 2:**
I've modified initial version to this:

```
public class Mapping2<TSource>
{
    private readonly Delegate setter;

    public Mapping2(Expression<Func<TSource, object>> expression)
    {
        var newValue = Expression.Parameter(expression.Body.Type);
        var body = Expression.Assign(expression.Body, newValue);
        var assign = Expression.Lambda(body, expression.Parameters[0], newValue);            

        setter = assign.Compile();
    }

    public void Assign(TSource instance, object value)
    {
        setter.DynamicInvoke(instance, value);
    }
}
```

And it almost works.
By almost I mean it works with reference type properties, and with value type properties I get:

> System.ArgumentException : Expression must be writeable
>   Parameter name: left

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like Assign to be Assign<TResult> and Mapping => Mapping<TSource> ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Maybe the approach of [AutoMapper's QueryableExtensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/QueryableExtensions.cs) will inspire you. They use a two-phase projection to be able to keep the two generic parameters apart.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I've updated question with more concrete example, hope that will help understand what I need.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing [`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.org/). Do you really need to do that? Why not simply use AutoMapper?

Comment: I was having idea to use AutoMapper for this and in result I may end up using it, but I found a problem that I can't solve by my self although it's definition looks quite simple, so I thought it would be great to know how such kind problems are solved (because this is not the first time I need to rethink code to avoid generic parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to do it, source code below. It runs somewhat faster than Automapper (not sure if my Automapper configuration is the fastest for this task), benchmark is not bulletproof, but on my machine to map 5 million rows took 20.16 seconds using my written mapper and 39.90 using Automapper, although it seems that Automapper uses less memory for this task (haven't measured it, but with 10 million rows Automapper gives result and my mapper fails with OutOfMemory).

```
public class MappingParameter<TSource>
{
    private readonly Delegate setter;

    private MappingParameter(Delegate compiledSetter)
    {
        setter = compiledSetter;
    }

    public static MappingParameter<TSource> Create<TResult>(Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression)
    {
        var newValue = Expression.Parameter(expression.Body.Type);
        var body = Expression.Assign(expression.Body, newValue);
        var assign = Expression.Lambda(body, expression.Parameters[0], newValue);

        var compiledSetter = assign.Compile();

        return new MappingParameter<TSource>(compiledSetter);
    }

    public void Assign(TSource instance, object value)
    {
        object convertedValue;
        if (!setter.Method.ReturnType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)))
        {
            convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, setter.Method.ReturnType);
        }
        else
        {
            convertedValue = value;
        }

        setter.DynamicInvoke(instance, convertedValue);
    }
}

public class DataRowMappingConfiguration<TSource>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, MappingParameter<TSource>> mappings =
        new Dictionary<string, MappingParameter<TSource>>();

    public DataRowMappingConfiguration<TSource> Add<TResult>(string columnName,
                                                             Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression)
    {
        mappings.Add(columnName, MappingParameter<TSource>.Create(expression));
        return this;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, MappingParameter<TSource>> Mappings
    {
        get
        {
            return mappings;
        }
    }
}

public class DataRowMapper<TSource>
{
    private readonly DataRowMappingConfiguration<TSource> configuration;

    public DataRowMapper(DataRowMappingConfiguration<TSource> configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TSource> Map(DataTable table)
    {
        var list = new List<TSource>(table.Rows.Count);

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.Rows)
        {
            var obj = (TSource)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TSource));

            foreach (var mapping in configuration.Mappings)
            {
                mapping.Value.Assign(obj, dataRow[mapping.Key]);
            }

            list.Add(obj);
        }

        return list;
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class DataRowMappingTests
{      
    [Test]
    public void ShouldMapPropertiesUsingOwnMapper()
    {            
        var mappingConfiguration = new DataRowMappingConfiguration<TestClass>()
            .Add("firstName", x => x.Name)
            .Add("age", x => x.Age);

        var mapper = new DataRowMapper<TestClass>(mappingConfiguration);                      

        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("firstName");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("age");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        {
            var row = dataTable.NewRow();
            row["firstName"] = "John";
            row["age"] = 15;

            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);                
        }

        var start = DateTime.Now;

        var result = mapper.Map(dataTable).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds);

        Assert.AreEqual("John", result.First().Name);
        Assert.AreEqual(15, result.First().Age);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ShouldMapPropertyUsingAutoMapper()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<DataRow, TestClass>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.MapFrom(y => y["firstName"]))
            .ForMember(x => x.Age, x => x.MapFrom(y => y["age"]));

        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("firstName");
        dataTable.Columns.Add("age");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++)
        {
            var row = dataTable.NewRow();
            row["firstName"] = "John";
            row["age"] = 15;

            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        var start = DateTime.Now;

        var result = dataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(Mapper.Map<DataRow, TestClass>).ToList();         

        Console.WriteLine((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds);

        Assert.AreEqual("John", result.First().Name);
        Assert.AreEqual(15, result.First().Age);
    }
}
```

Comment: getting rid of `TResult` is not really good. You see you're relying on `Delegate.DynamicInvoke`. That will hurt. A good share of your 20 seconds is spent there.

Answer (score 1):

Something like thid maybe :

```
public class Mapping<TSource>
{
    public void Assign<TResult>(TSource instance, TResult value)
    {
        var property = typeof(TSource).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(TResult)));
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.SetValue(instance, value, new object[0]);
        }

    }
}
```

***But your object need to have ONE property of each type for this to be accurate***

We could even make it more generic, but more dangerous :

```
    public void Assign<TResult>(TSource instance, TResult value)
    {
        var property = typeof(TSource).GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TResult)));
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.SetValue(instance, value, new object[0]);
        }

    }
```

(this won't work if you have 2 properties inheriting from the same base class)...

Comment: That could work, just I think I would need to cache propertyinfo's somewhere to avoid reflection performace hit. From other side, I would like to see solution using Expressions :)

Comment: Yes, I think I dod not enirely understand your requirement with configuration as a separate class...